# FieldError: Unsupported lookup 'unaccent' for CharField or join on the field not permitted

Tags: django

I am getting `FieldError: Unsupported lookup 'unaccent' for CharField or join on the field not permitted`. Any help is appreciated. Any ideas?

```
#template
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" method="GET" action="{% url 'search' %}" value="{{request.get.q}}">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="q" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" >
        </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>

#views.py
def Search(request):
    queryset_list=Testimony.objects.all().order_by('timestamp')
    if request.user.is_staff or request.user.is_superuser:
        queryset_list=Testimony.objects.all()

    print('1')
    if request.method=='GET':
        query=request.GET.get("q")
        print('2')
        queryset_list = Testimony.objects.filter(
            Q(title__unaccent__lower__trigram_similar=query)|
            Q(body__unaccent__lower__trigram_similar=query)|
            Q(username__unaccent__lower__trigram_similar=query)
            #Q(firstname__unaccent__lower__trigram_similar__icontains=query)
            ).distinct().order_by('timestamp')


    print('3')
    paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 20)
    page_request_var="page"
    page=request.GET.get(page_request_var)
    try:
        queryset=paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        queryset=paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        queryset=paginator.page(paginator_num.pages)

    print('4')
    context={
    "object_list": queryset,
    "title":"list",
    "page_request_var":page_request_var,
    }

    return render(request, 'search.html', {'queryset_list':queryset_list})
```

Traceback points to:
 `Q(username__unaccent__lower__trigram_similar=query)`

Comment: Both `unaccent` and `trigram_similar` are provided by the `'django.contrib.postgres'` app. Did you add that to INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: Thanks! It worked.

Comment: Thanks you, for some reason I had to activate these extention on my database, done so by following the answer to this question: https://www.semicolonworld.com/question/84542/fielderror-unsupported-lookup-for-charfield-or-join-on-the-field-not-permitted-on-django

Answer (score 12):

For Django at least 1.11 ([source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/lookups/#unaccent)) and PostgreSQL at least 8.5 ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619848/how-to-have-accent-insensitive-filter-in-django-with-postgres))

- Add the line `django.contrib.postgres` in INSTALLED_APPS (`settings.py`)
- Activate the `unaccent` extension

  - run `CREATE EXTENSION unaccent;` at PgAdmin ([source](https://github.com/cursame/cursame-rails/wiki/CREATE-EXTENSION-unaccent;-(PostgreSQL))) or...
  - create an empty migration (`./manage.py makemigrations --empty your.application.name`) and edit the generated file with the following content ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31382675/how-can-i-activate-the-unaccent-extension-on-an-already-existing-model)) and, finally, running `./manage.py migrate`:

[other reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/operations/#django.contrib.postgres.operations.UnaccentExtension)

```
from django.contrib.postgres.operations import UnaccentExtension

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

dependencies = [
    (<snip>)
]

operations = [
    UnaccentExtension()
]
```

Trivia: It didn't work at `admin.py`, but did worked at other `.py` files.

Comment: Excelent entry!.. Just to add that the empty migration script should be modified to `./manage.py makemigrations --empty your.application.name`