# Django - query CharFields ignoring diacritic signs

Tags: django, django-orm

Is there a way in Django to filter some `CharField`/`TextField` using string containing only ASCII characters but matching records in the database that may contain non-ASCII characters?

eg. I would like below code to find a city with `name` set to Köln:

```py
from django.db import models

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

City.objects.filter(name__<some lookup>='koln')
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the answer for my question was actualy `unaccent` lookup since I am using PostgreSQL.
Here are the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/lookups/#unaccent

This lookup field does not work right off the bat, first one needs to install [unaccent extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/unaccent.html).

Credits to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55050439/7301831) - easy way to do that is to create empty migration and add [unaccent extension with Django](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55050439/7301831).

```sh
python manage.py makemigrations --empty <app_name>
```

Then in the new migration file:

```py
from django.db import migrations
from django.contrib.postgres.operations import UnaccentExtension


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('app_name', '<parent_migration>'),
    ]

    operations = [
        UnaccentExtension(),
    ]
```

Now I can do desired query like this:

```py
City.objects.filter(name__unaccent__iexact='koln')
```

And it works just as expected :)