Djagno ORM diacritic and case insensitive query with matching at least 3 chars
I'd like to query the columns "title" and "content" of the following django model w postgresql integration in a diacritic- and casing-insensitive way. The query should return articles when the string "Ronald" is present in either of these columns, for every of the following user inputs: "ronálD", "Ron" and even "ronald reagan" for example.
class Article(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    content = models.TextField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    length = models.IntegerField(default=4, null=True)
    thumbnail = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    img_location = ArrayField(models.TextField(), blank=True, default=list, null=True)

Thanks for the assistance!
I came as far as returning articles casing and diacritic-insensitively w substring matching, but did not manage to return articles when only a set of letters are matching: eg: "Reagen" for the input "Ronald Reagan", or when querying multiple columns:
from django.db.models import Func, Value, F, Q


class Unaccent(Func):
    function = 'unaccent'

class Lower(Func):
    function = 'lower'
        
def normalize_field(field_name, is_array=False):
    if is_array:
        return Unaccent(Lower(F(field_name), function='unnest'))
    return Lower(Unaccent(F(field_name)))

normalized_term = Lower(Unaccent(Value(input_term)))

articles = list(Article.objects.annotate(
                normalized_content=normalize_field('content'),
            ).filter(
                Q(normalized_content__icontains=normalized_term) 
            ).order_by("-id").values()[:20]) 


You actually don't need to create that Unaccent function. It's available as a lookup for PostgreSQL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58105526/django-query-charfields-ignoring-diacritic-signs

__icontains is a command that ignores case, so why was it implemented separately?
